# MongoDB single node Replica Set not initializing correctly in podman pod after using as a standalone container

Tags: java, mongodb, docker, podman, replicaset

I have a Java Spring-Boot application accessing a mongoDB. Because I need transactions the mongoDB is set up as a single node replica set.
I have the following Dockerfile for the mongoDB:

```
#DockerfileMongo
FROM docker.io/mongo:6.0.1
COPY scripts/init-mongodb.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
RUN openssl rand -base64 756 > file.key
RUN chmod 400 file.key
RUN chown 999:999 file.key
```

The `init-mongodb.js`-File creates a non admin user `dev` with the password `pass` and some other initial Data for the Application.
I use the following script to start the mongo-container with podman within wsl:

```
# run_mongo.sh
echo "# Creating image"
sudo podman build -t localhost/my-mongo:latest -f ./DockerfileMongo

echo "# Run Container"
sudo podman run -dt -p 27017:27017 --name my-mongo-container --hostname my-mongo-container \
  -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin_user \
    -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin_pass \
  -e MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=developmentDB \
  -v mongo-datadir:/data/db \
  localhost/my-mongo:latest \
  --port 27017 \
  --keyFile file.key \
  --replSet rs0 \
  --bind_ip_all
```

For Testing and Development this setup works great - I can start and stop the mongoDB if needed and start my java application from my IDE.

I have a second script which starts my java-app and mongoDB containerized together:

```
# DockerfileJava
FROM docker.io/openjdk:17-jdk-slim
COPY target/my-java-app-*.jar may-java-app.jar 

ENV MONGO-DB-ADRESS="mongodb://dev:pass@localhost:27017/?authSource=developmentDB"

EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/my-java-app.jar"]
```

after building my application using `mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage` I am trying to use the following script to start the java app with the mongoDB together:

```
# run_app_with_mongo.sh
echo "# Creating images"

sudo podman build -t localhost/my-mongo:latest -f ./DockerfileMongo
sudo podman build -t localhost/my-java-app:latest -f ./DockerfileJava
echo "# Creating Pod"
sudo podman pod create --name my-pod -p 8081:8081 -p 27017:27017


echo "# Run Container"

sudo podman run -dt --pod my-pod --name my-mongo-container \
  -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin_user \
  -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin_pass \
  -e MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=developmentDB \
  -v mongo-datadir:/data/db \
  localhost/my-mongo:latest \
  --port 27017 \
  --keyFile file.key \
  --replSet rs0 \
  --bind_ip_all

sleep 20
# waiting 20 seconds for mongo startup
sudo podman exec -it my-mongo-container bash -c "mongosh --host localhost:27017 -u admin_user -p admin_pass --eval \"rs.initiate()\""

sudo podman run -dt --pod my-pod -e MONGO-DB-ADRESS=mongodb://dev:pass@localhost:27017/?authSource=developmentDB --name my-java-app-container localhost/my-java-app:latest
```

When I use the first script `run_mongo.sh` everything works. Then after stopping my mongo container and deleting the image and then try to run the second script `run_app_with_mongo.sh` the containers are starting but I get the following message from my java app:

> INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:5}] to localhost:27017
> INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_GHOST, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[6, 0, 1]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=17, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=3951055, setName='null', canonicalAddress=null, hosts=[], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='null', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=null, lastWriteDate=null, lastUpdateTimeNanos=3660922456911}

And Queries fail with

> Query failed with error code 13436 and error message 'node is not in primary or recovering state' on server localhost:27017

When I stop the Containers and delete the volume and just run the second script it all works fine.

How can I reuse the same volume and resolve the issue with the `REPLICA_SET_GHOST`?
When I use a different Volume in the second script it works but I don't have the same data for testing....

Comment: Try to add `while (! db.hello().isWritablePrimary ) sleep(1000);` after the `rs.initiate()`